# Unit Tests, how to simulate return of null data to get a 100% coverage

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit

I have the following API controllers which gets data from some master tables (for dropdowns) in a web UI.

```
public List<Personas> GetPersonas()
{
    try
    {
        ListService = new ListService();
        var listPersonas = ListService.GetPersonas();

        if (listPersonas == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return listPersonas.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(
        Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.Message));
    }
}
```

Then in the Unit Tests, I have this:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void GetAllPersonas_ShouldReturnAllPersonas()
 {
     var controller = new ListasController();

     controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage
     {
         RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/Listas/GetPersonas")
     };

     controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
     controller.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

     controller.RequestContext.RouteData = new HttpRouteData(
         route: new HttpRoute(),
         values: new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Listas" } });

     var response = controller.GetPersonas() as List<Personas>;
     Assert.IsNotNull(response);
     Assert.AreEqual(response[0].IdPersona, 1);
     Assert.IsInstanceOfType(response, typeof(List<Personas>));

 }
```

Code works fine, but code coverage is about 50%, because it never this the statement inside the IF, because data is coming from a database, and that table is never empty.

How can I guarantee a 100% code coverage in this case? should I remove the IF? or can I emulate something here?

Thanks

Comment: The controller is tightly coupled to `ListService` which makes replacing it during unit tests difficult as the controller is in control of creating that dependency. Invert that control by injecting it as a explicit dependency to the controller. this will allow you mock/replace it with a stand in during unit testing to satisfy your testing scenarios.

Comment: If `ListService.GetPersonas` never returns `null` there's no point in checking for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to inject in an IListService, rather than new it up inside the GetPersonas call.
Then you can (in your unit test) stub / mock that object to have it return a list, or null, or whatever you want.

Have a squiz at https://autofac.org/ and http://nsubstitute.github.io/ .

Answer (score 1):

Are you intending to create an integration test? Or do you want to create a unit test?

If you want to create a unit test, the ListService dependency must be abstracted. Once abstracted you can mock or fake the dependency. Once mocked or faked you can create tests that handle various return occurrences for the ListService dependency, i.e. a standard return, null returns, and/or possible exceptions.